Here's your hat. What's your hurry? Meaning
Here's your hat. What's your hurry?
I know this idiom means generally to leave. I understand the hat part, because when we leave we put on our hats. But then "what's your hurry?" implies why are you so quick to leave? So I don't understand this contradiction. Can someone explain it ot me thank you.

This seems to be Groucho Marx humor. The incongruity is the basis of that humor.
“Hello, I must be going.” “You can leave in a huff. Or you can leave in a minute and a huff.”  “From the moment I picked up your book until I put it down, I was convulsed with laughter. Some day I intend reading it.” “I have nothing but respect for you -- and not much of that.”

@DrMoishePippik: Here's Your Hat What's Your Hurry is also a collection of short stories by Elizabeth McCracken first published in 1993 that now seems to be popular in the online TEFL world.

I don't think this is an "idiom".  There is some irony in the second phrase. It only makes sense when you realise that both people in the conversation are not telling the whole truth.
The full form is in reply to someone saying "I should go now." This kind of comment might be literal, or it might be a conversational gambit to get the other person to ask them to stay.
The reply is another "conversational gambit", by offering the person's hat (probably figuratively, since nobody wears hats anymore) and then ironically or sarcastically asking them to stay. The first person is forced either to admit that they don't want to leave (and that saying "I should go" was not true) or to leave. But since admitting to lying is difficult, the person would probably go.
But don't use this as an idiom.  It is not something that has any use outside of "collections of English sayings".  Nobody ever actually says this.

I have seven hats at the moment. A black wool fedora, a grey linen one, a black beanie, a black woolly hat, and a real French beret, a 'Super Foulard', from Tolouse. I'm looking for an Oppenheimer hat right now, but I am balking at the price of a Stetson Boss of The Plains at $300 plus. It's like a pork pie hat with a Western style broad brim. It's very important that the crown isn't 'pinched'.

Okay,  nobody else wears hats.

I wrote seven but only listed five. I also have a real yellow oilskin 'Sou'Wester' and a collapsible 'opera' top hat, but the latter is not for serious wearing, except at Dickens themed fancy-dress parties.

I mean, to be fair, I have a felt fedora, a cheap pork-pie hat (as a stage prop) a crochet elf-hat, two or three assorted bobble hats, two cloth sun hats (one has benefited from a winter being buried in a long jump pit) and a nike baseball cap that I found abandoned.   Which makes 8...

My cousin told me he had to stop wearing pork-pie hats, because the gravy kept running down his neck.

I've heard people say it, generally to describe a situation where someone was sent away in haste or in confusion. I'm not sure what "Nobody ever actually says this" means, since clearly people do or there wouldn't be a question about it.
